# Recreate pandas dataframe from question in stackoverflow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a question from someone who tries to answer questions about pandas dataframes. Consider a question with a given dataset which is just the visualization (not the actual code), for example:

```
   numbers letters       dates         all
0        1       a  20-10-2020         NaN
1        2       b  21-10-2020           b
2        3       c  20-11-2020           4
3        4       d  20-10-2021  20-10-2020
4        5       e  10-10-2020        3.14
```

Is it possible to quickly import this in python as a dataframe or as a dictionary? So far I copied the given text and transformed it to a dataframe by making strings (adding `''`) and so on.

I think there are two 'solutions' for this:

1. Make a function that given the text as input, it somehow transforms it to a dataframe.
2. Use some function in the text-editor (I use spyder) which can do this trick for us.

Comment: `df = pd.read_clipboard()`

Comment: @MustafaAydın can you elaborate a bit more? Do you save it first as a txt file?

Comment: i copy the dataframe with ctrl+c, then run that code. it reads from the clipboard

Comment: this is mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples for reference.

Comment: Ah perfect! Works like magic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

##### `read_clipboard`

You can use [`pd.read_clipboard()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html) optionally with a separator (e.g. `pd.read_clipboard('\s\s+')` if you have datetime strings or spaces in column names and columns are separated by at least two spaces):

- select text on the question and copy to clipboard (ctrl+c/command-c)
- move to python shell or notebook and run `pd.read_clipboard()`

Note that this doesn't work well on all platforms.

##### `read_csv` + `io.StringIO`

For more complex formats, combine [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) combined with [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO):

```
data = '''
   numbers letters       dates         all
0        1       a  20-10-2020         NaN
1        2       b  21-10-2020           b
2        3       c  20-11-2020           4
3        4       d  20-10-2021  20-10-2020
4        5       e  10-10-2020        3.14
'''

import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
df
```